# In Expect script, how do you perform simple math and assign the result to a variable?

Tags: expect

Learning this language has been difficult because of the very particular syntax required. Everything needs a strange set of braces or brackets or quotes, and I'm pulling out my hair trying to keep it all straight. I can find examples of everything I already know how to do, and I can even find partial examples of what I'm trying to do, but apparently this is such a simple and beginner thing that nobody has bothered to demonstrate it. Either that or I am getting old and I am losing my Google-fu.

I have two variables, thing1 and thing2. I have abandoned my actual code until I figure out how to do 2 + 2, so for now the value of thing1 is 2 and the value of thing2 is 2. I have tried:

```
set thing_total expr thing1+thing2
set thing_total expr (thing1+thing2)
set thing_total expr [thing1+thing2]
set thing_total expr {thing1+thing2}
set thing_total expr [ thing1+thing2 ]
set thing_total expr [ thing1 + thing2 ]
set thing_total [expr $thing1+$thing2]
set thing_total [expr ($thing1+$thing2)]
set thing_total [expr {$thing1+$thing2}]
set thing_total [expr [ $thing1 + $thing2 ] ]
```

plus a bunch more that I'm not gonna bother to list. Can someone please tell me how to do math and assign the result to a variable? Don't care about floating point or integer or anything to do with data types.

Comment: Yes, this is a bit of a wart on the Tcl language. You want `set thing_total [expr {$thing1+$thing2}]` -- It's an unavoidable consequence of the rules of Tcl syntax. See https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/expr.htm

Comment: Expect uses the [tag:tcl] language. Try my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) if you are more comfortable with shell scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, glenn, for getting me on the right track. To get it to work, I had to add spaces:

```
set thing_total [ expr { $thing1 - $thing2 } ]
```

Trying to run the code without spaces gave me the same errors:

```
invalid command name "expr{2+2}"
    while executing
"expr{$thing1+$thing2}"
    invoked from within
"set thing_total [expr{$thing1+$thing2}]"
    (file "./adder.sh" line 11)
```

Not sure if the spaces need to be inserted between the variables and the brackets or between the variables and the operands, so I just added spaces everywhere.